# How to pass email verification account in allauth, while seeding database

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Cant find the way how to create user inside seed.py with passed verification( I have email verification in my project which is set up as mandatory). User creation works, but i want activated account.
I am using django-allauth package.Setting up `verificated/is_active = True` does not help.
Here is my `seed.py`:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument(
        "--create_user",
        action="store_true",
        help="Create user",
    )
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if options["create_user"]:
        # ToDo: find the way to pass account verification
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
            first_name="A",
            last_name="A",
            email="test@test.com",
            password="Password123",
        )
        for _ in range(2):
            EventFactory.create(
                is_checked_by_admin=True,
                private=False,
                host=user,
                event_starts=datetime(1987, 8, 15, 9, 51, 25),
            )
            EventFactory.create(
                is_checked_by_admin=True,
                private=False,
                host=user,
            )
```

Here is `account_manager`:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
        self,
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        password,
    ):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("User must have an email"))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_("User must have a password"))
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_("User must have a first name"))
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_("User must have a last name"))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        custom_user = self.model(
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        custom_user.set_password(password)
        custom_user.save()
        return custom_user
```

Thank you for any help!